# variable assignment from inside a bash script

Tags: bash

This is obviously an SSCCE, so it makes (in itself) no sense. E.g. the variable assignment to `Y` is not used in this minimal example; I'm just trying to figure out the correct syntax to use for my actual case.

I can do the following directly on the bash shell:

```
Y=10 echo foo
```

I can also have the following in a bash file `foo.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
X="echo foo"
$X
```

... and then do a:

```
$./foo.sh
foo
```

However, when I have the following in a bash file:

```
#!/bin/bash
X="Y=10 echo foo"
$X
```

... then, I get:

```
$ ./foo.sh 
./foo.sh: line 3: Y=10: command not found
```

What's the correct syntax to use for the above?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that the optional parameter assignments are recognized *before* parameter expansion occurs, so the line

```
$X
```

is recognized as a command with no preceding assignments. The first word of the result of expanding it is assumed to be the command name, so the shell tries to run `Y=10`.

As is usually the case, you should not try to store code in a variable, but rather in a function.

```
X () {
    Y=10 echo foo
}
```

Answer (score 0):

*It turned out that what I describe below is just an artifact of the minimal example, which leaves out the part where `Y` is used.*

There is a variable assignment before the command in the line:

```
Y=10 echo foo
```

The assignment will set the variable `Y` to `10` during the execution of `echo foo`. Because `echo foo` makes no use of `Y`, the assignment does not have an effect.

In all variants of this command in the question and the answers, that's the same - the `Y=10` has no effect there.

Comment: that's correct; I've updated the question to make that clear.

Comment: Ok; I added a note, and keep it for now for other readers who get confused or curious about that. Feell free to vote down.

Answer (score 0):

If you must do this, use `env`:

```
$ X='env Y=10 echo foo'
foo
```

...and to demonstrate `$Y`...

```
$ X='env Y=10 env'
$ $X | grep \^Y
Y=10
```

...but a function is better.

Answer (score -1):

The way to get a command to be parsed again after parameter expansion occurs is

```
X="Y=10 echo foo"
eval "$X"
```

I'm assuming that you have a realistic reason for wanting to do this.